# Batch file to rename recursive folder

Tags: recursion, rename, subdirectory, batch-rename

I saw this answer in the forum.
To rename the folder

```
C:\test\1\old
C:\test\2\old
C:\test\3\old
```

to become

```
C:\test\1\new
C:\test\2\new
C:\test\3\new
```

with the code

```
@echo off

FOR /D %%D IN ("C:\test\*") DO CALL :RENAME %%D

:RENAME
SET CRITERIA=\old
FOR /D %%R IN (%1%CRITERIA%) DO RENAME %%R "new"
```

It is working.

For me I want to add more

```
C:\test\1\old
C:\test\2\temp\old
C:\test\3\old
```

```
C:\test\1\new
C:\test\2\new
C:\test\3\new
```

The above code is not working for my above example with one more subfolder.  Any help please.

Comment: You can't do it with the same code. `C:\test\2\temp\old` requires removing an extra folder as well as doing the rename you want, which is more difficult.

Comment: Hi Ken,  Thanks and can you help me how to solve this.